# GSuite sso login issue

Tags: java, google-app-engine, single-sign-on, google-apps

I have created an SSO application in app engine for G Suite. Normally it is working fine but when users are trying to login between the time 5:30am - 6:30am IST(UTC timing 00:00hours - 01:00hours),they are getting the following issue:

"This service cannot be accessed because your login credentials are not yet valid. Please log in and try again."

As per Google's solution it is asking to 'Check the clock on your Identity Provider's server'.The IDP here is Google app engine.Can anyone please help me out with the solution?

Comment: I would check with G-Suite, if G-Suite is your IDP and Okta is your SP (meaning, users are redirected from your app to G-Suite to log in, they authenticate with their G-Suite credentials, and are then redirected back to your app with the authentication result)

Answer (score 0):

so, the app you're making is an Identity Provider itself and not an app that just uses SSO / SAML to authenticate into the app? i.e. you're making a OneLogin / Okta / etc replacement within App Engine?

Comment: Hi,thank you for commenting and apologies for late reply. Though I did not get what you are asking but I found out a solution. When the hours is 00 it is getting this error.So at that 00 hours I am replacing the time explicitly by 01 on which the error is not occuring anymore.